# Recover from ubuntu getting stuck

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I've been using ubuntu 12.04 for a while now and i get my work lost so many times because of this freezing issue.

Only the mouse pointer works when it freezes.

I had Gnome installed right after i install Ubuntu. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common bug happens to be unsolved in Gnome for a long time. I've experienced this so many times that i got used to it. You can use a simple method.

1. Hit **`alt + ctrl + F1`**
   Now you'll see ubuntu tty1.
2. Login with your ubuntu username and password. (Make sure not to use numeric pad when inserting the password)
3. Now enter **`gnome-shell --display :0 --replace`** and hit return.
4. Wait for a while and return back to your display by hitting **`alt + ctrl + F7`**.

Now just wait a bit and you'll see the complete Gnome-shell resets. Then you're good to go.

Comment: i'll check this method when it freezes next time and get back to you. Thank you very much for the quick response. :)

Comment: Ok. It just got stuck & i used this method. Awesome. Worked like charm. This saves my life. Thank you so so much :D :D

Comment: Happy to know you worked it out. But remember this method won't work in instances like memory overload.